# компиляция файла python на windows для mac os

Tags: python, компиляция

Доброе утро , мне надо скомпилировать `python` код для `mac-os` , сам я на windows сижу , как мне можно это сделать ?

Comment: А зачем компилировать, на мак тоже питон можно поставить )

Comment: у меня нету мака но есть у клиента , он не будет разбираться как ставить + ещё скачивать расширения. так что сказал что бы я скомпелировал.

Comment: Как вариант можно написать sh файл, который все зависимости будет устанавливать

Comment: А, ну еще Docker как вариант. Остается объяснить клиенту как установить докер, и потом одной командой запускать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно скачать VirtualBox ([здесь](https://www.virtualbox.org/)), установить macos, на мак python и скомпелировать, а от туда уже на свой. Это в кратце. У меня самого есть VirtualBox по этому я могу скомпелровать.

Comment: Цитата: PyInstaller когда-то пытался поддерживать кросс-компиляцию (из Linux -> Windows), но позже отказался от этой идеи .